# VBA Excel. How to search for a value, get the first row/first column values and insert them in a different sheet if they don't yet exist

Tags: vba, excel, search, insert

I have a workbook for project tracking with two sheets. Sheet1 is the overview and Sheet2 is for involvement.
I need a code to do the following:
1. Find the "x" used to mark a person as assigned to a project
2. Get the project name
3. Go to Sheet2, lookup the person with the project, and if the project is not there, insert it

```
Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'Turn off screen updating
Dim searchSheet1 As Range
Dim name As String
Dim searchSheet2 As Range
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set searchSheet1 = Range("D4", "S60") 'defined a larger area...
For Each cell In searchSheet1
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "x") > 0 Then
name = Cells(searchSheet1.Column).Text 'name that is assigned on project
'find the project to copy - row/column
 Range("A" & searchSheet1.Row, "B" & searchSheet1.Row).Select
 Range("A" & searchSheet1.Row, "B" & searchSheet1.Row).Copy
'search in Sheet2 for the name and project
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
'''''''If I use For again I get an error

'Inserting command
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGcTg.png)
[image: Sheet2]

This is what I was able to do... But I got stuck...
If anybody could help me out I would appreciate it
Thank you

Comment: Are the project names Book Marks (hyperlinks)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? `name = Cells(searchSheet1.Column).Text` This doesn't really make any sense... Also, what do you mean by *"If I use For again I get an error"*? What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

```
Feature List:
 1. Compiles a list of Projects and Employees from Sheet1
 2. Adds the Employees to the Project Lists
 3. Highlights any Employee improperly Assigned to a Project
 4. Projects not on Sheets are appended with there assigned Employees

Sub SynchonizeProject()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arData, d As New Dictionary, d2
    Dim k As String, v As String
    Dim e As Range, p As Range, p2 As Range
    'The First Employee Names
    Set e = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")
    'The First Project Names
    Set p = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
    'The First Project Names
    Set p2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arData = Range(p.End(xlDown), e.End(xlToRight))
    For i = 2 To UBound(arData, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(arData, 2)
            If UCase(arData(i, j)) = "X" Then
                'Key: Project-Name
                k = arData(i, 1)
                'Value: Employee-Name
                v = arData(1, j)
                If Not d.Exists(k) Then
                    Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    d.Add k, d2
                End If
                d(k).Add v, k
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ProcessEmployees d, p2
End Sub
Sub ProcessEmployees(d, p2 As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim arData, k As String, k2, d2
    Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With p2.Worksheet
        Do
            k = p2
            'If there are no projects dump the list
            If Len(k) = 0 Then InsertRows d, p2
            'TargetCell is a Project Name
            If d.Exists(k) Then
                'Insert the newly assigned Employees here
                If d2.Count Then InsertRows d2, p2
                ' Retrieve the next set of employees
                Set d2 = d(k)
                'Remove the Project from the list
                d.Remove k
                'Exception: 1st project had no assignments
                If d.Exists(p2.Offset(1).Text) Then InsertRows d2, p2
            ElseIf d2.Exists(k) Then
                d2.Remove k
            ElseIf Len(k) Then
                'The Cell is neither an Employee or Project so highlight it
                p2.Offset(i).Interior.Color = 65535
            End If
            Set p2 = p2.Offset(1)
        Loop Until Loop Until p2.Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, p2.Column).End(xlUp).Row = p2.Row
    End With
    'Insert New Projects
    InsertRows d, p2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub InsertRows(d, p2 As Range)
    Dim k
    With p2.Worksheet
        For Each k In d.keys
            If Len(p2) Then
                p2.Offset(1).Rows.EntireRow.Insert _
                        Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                Set p2 = p2.Offset(1)
            End If
            p2 = k
            If IsObject(d(k)) Then InsertRows d(k), p2
            d.Remove k
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer Thomas.
This code does the job almost how I need it, but it is a bit too advanced for me do alter it to my exact specification... Currently your code creates a list with projects and employees assigned to it, and I need it a bit different.
Would you be able to alter your code to do the following?
1. Search in sheet2 for the employee name that has a project assigned in Sheet1
2. Look in the project list of that employee
3. If the project is not there, insert it in that employees list of projects.

Comment: I would manage the information differently. [Download Procect Assignments.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vse28tg2uhf5rx2/Project%20Assignments.xlsx?dl=0) It you rearrange your data this way it will be much easier to work with.  You'll be able to use standard Excel techniques to accomplish your goals.